# How to generate token for appstore API access in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt, app-store

In the link below is explained how to generate JWT token with header and payload to access the Apple API
However I don't see how to combine header and payload.
Can someone make an example in ruby

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP is asking the community to write code for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [jwt gem](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt). It's a well-maintained library with regular updates. It's probably possible to do it without a gem too, but anything having to do with security should be air-tight in production, so I would just go with the gem.

Look for the correct encryption algorithm (Apple seems to be using ES256) and find it in the documentation to see an example of how to create a token with that.

The format for creating a basic JWT token with the gem (custom header fields are optional) is this:

```rb
JWT.encode your_payload, your_private_key, encryption_algorithm, custom_header_fields
```